# MVC Deployment resource URLS not resolving

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, resources

My URLs aren't resolving correctly.
When I deploy my app name is omitted from the urls.
Its suppose to be:
http:////Content/images/ect
But it gets rendered as 
http:///Content/images/ect
which obviously doesn't resolve.
My URLS looks like this:

```
<img src="/Content/images/Misc/Lock.png" />
```

If I add a ~ to the url (before content) it resolves perfectly when deployed, but breaks in my dev environment.

This being a MVC app means I also have a few ajax calls to actions (controller/action/) which also does not resolve, breaking most of the site.

I deployed under the default web site in IIS, moving it to another site is not an option.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `Url.Content`?

It would be something like this (untested)

`<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Misc/Lock.png")" />`

Comment: Thanks Rick. That resolves the issue with my images, but my ajax calls are still not working. The calls happen in a script file, so the HTML helpers aren't available there.

Comment: Without seeing your system or how complex the javascript is, one solution I've used successfully would be to render a hidden '<a href=... />' element in the view and use the MVC extension methods to create the ajax url.  This way if your route tables change, your ajax call is updated automatically.  Then use your javascript to target the anchor by ID and get the ajax url.

Comment: The calls aren't anything fancy. Simple Ajax calls from a script file that gets include in the views using script tags

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ json })
    }).done(function (resp) {

Comment: It would be simple for you to implement my suggestion then.  It's how I got around the same issue you are having, and it has the side benefit of future proofing your URLs.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I used a combination of your and Maess' answer

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your host, if you are running this site as a sub site and not under its own IIS site, the host requires the ~.  I have gotten around this by using a global javascript variable to hold the site root.  I populate the variable in the main site layout like so:

```
var gSiteRoot = '@MvcHtmlString.Create(Url.Content("~/"))';
```

Then when I need to construct a url in js I use it like so:

```
 var url = gSiteRoot + 'restofurl';
```

Comment: The reason I do it this way is that you can't use HTML helpers in js files.  If you don't use js files, just use Rick B's suggestion.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the alternative to what I suggested, and a good solution.  What you choose should depend on what makes the most sense for the system you are building.

Comment: Thanks Maess! I used a combination of your and Rick's answer. unfortunately I can only mark one reply as the answer.